# How to obtain info of the program from the window list with CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I managed to get list of windows on the desktop with CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, but the next time is to try to get the properties of the window, like the program name, title, and other properties.

What API should I look into and do we have any example on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List the windows and retrieve the specific information while looping through:

```
NSMutableArray *windows = (NSMutableArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);

for (NSDictionary *window in windows) {
    NSString *owner = [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowOwnerName" ];
    NSString *name = [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowName" ];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@",owner,name);
}
```

Available keys:

```
kCGWindowIsOnscreen
kCGWindowLayer 
kCGWindowMemoryUsage
kCGWindowName
kCGWindowNumber
kCGWindowOwnerName
kCGWindowOwnerPID
kCGWindowSharingState
kCGWindowStoreType
```

Comment: How about getting info like what kind of program, e.g., browser and if it's browser, get list of history etc.

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the "kind of application" this way. You can however check the `kCGWindowOwnerName` agains an predefined array containing all browsers. Example array: `NSArray *browsers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Safari", @"Firefox", @"Chrome", @"Opera", nil];` Example check: `[browsers containsObject:theOwnerName];`. Getting the browser history is completely different for every browser.

Comment: Do I need to do release for windows? [windows release];